# Using JSON extractor inside a WHILE controller in JMETER

Tags: json, while-loop, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to get JSON response which appears after some time of running a sample till then it is null, after some time it gives a "filestore_id" that is some random number. I am enable to write the condition in while loop for the loop to run till there is no null in the JSON response and extract the filestore_id from the JSON response which can be then used in a sample outside of that while loop.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C13Jp.jpg)

The file store id for loop 1 gives null.After some loops it gives some id number when the total records=recordscompleted.

[Attached screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cscuE.jpg)

[Attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Jia0.jpg)

[Attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJJ6Q.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

1. The "condition" would be a [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) like:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${filestore_id}" == "null",)}
   ```
2. I cannot give you either [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) or [JSON JMESPath Expression](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/) because you [preferred to post your JSON response as the image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), it could be something like:

   [image]